# Filesystem link in NativeScript project

Tags: angular, filesystems, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I´m building an app using nativescript. I want to have some code in other folder and put it on the project using a link, but doesn't work. When I do that I get this error:

```
../test.ts(4,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
```

The strange thing is that with the real file that doesn't happend, anyone know why this happens?

I'm using OsX and I create the link to the folder using

```
ln -s [originfolder] [desfolder]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you write where you saved link ? and what you used as origin folder ? or file ?

Comment: Hi! I used a folder as origin, and I save the link within the "app" folder

Comment: As long as you have @angular/core inside node_modules it should work without link so not sure why using links :/

Comment: I use links because I reuse the same code in different projects, the @angular/core is not the problem, if I replace the link with the original folder it works.

Comment: I discover that using typescript 1.8 works, I dont understand why...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with typescript version, I was using 2.0, now I'm using 1.8 and it works fine.